# Spring : Unable to resolve view name in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, spring-annotations

I do have gone through some solutions, none has work in my case.
I have been getting "Not Found" error on browser on running this simple spring mvc example. I am new to Spring framework. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Following is the error I get on Console when I run the program :

> WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-4) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Demo1/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'
>   WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-5) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Demo1/HelloPage] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'

Here is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Demo1</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.kurshit.springmvc.Demo1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"> 

 <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<context:component-scan base-package = "com.kurshit.springmvc.Demo1.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.kurshit.springmvc.Demo1.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome.html")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("HelloPage","msg","Welcome To Spring");


        return mav;

    }
}
```

HomePage.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>First Spring Example with Deployment Descriptor</h1>

    <h2>${msg}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is how my directory structure looks like :

[Directory Structure Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPmKz.jpg)

I am using Maven tool to resolve dependancies :

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jsp is called HomePage.jsp but you are returning HelloPage in your ModelAndView. These names need to match. (Although you don't need the .jsp extension in the ModelAndView)

Comment: I got it working changing mav to "ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/views/HelloPage.jsp","msg","Hey");" in Controller. Also, removing .jsp did not help. Shouldn't it have be optional?! Thanks a ton for insights.

Comment: What you did to fix it works but you really should be able to put just "HelloPage" as the first argument in the constructor. This implies to me that your viewResolver bean is not working correctly. I'm afraid I'm not sure why, I'm more used to Java based config than the old XML config for this bean. It may be because you didn't set a view class for the view resolver. (see http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial). You could also up logging to check that the view resolver bean is being initialized.